# leetcode bug? Cannot exit on a do/while loop under false condition. C language

Tags: c, algorithm, do-while

I add to leetcode to practice a bit.
I try to solve the second algo question:

> You are a product manager and currently leading a team to develop a new product. Unfortunately, the latest version of your product fails the quality check. Since each version is developed based on the previous version, all the versions after a bad version are also bad.
> Suppose you have n versions [1, 2, ..., n] and you want to find out the first bad one, which causes all the following ones to be bad.
> You are given an API bool isBadVersion(version) which returns whether version is bad. Implement a function to find the first bad version. You should minimize the number of calls to the API.

My solution works fine (I tested it on another editor) but on a leetcode it seems to not exit from the loop.

My code is here:

```
// The API isBadVersion is defined for you.
// bool isBadVersion(int version);

int firstBadVersion(int n) {

    int low = 0;
    int hight = n;
    int ret;
    int bad_1;
    int bad;
    int exit;

    do{
        ret = (low-hight==1) ? ret+1 : (hight+low)/2;
        
        bad_1 = isBadVersion(ret-1); // false if <= min_bad
        bad = isBadVersion(ret); // false if <= min_bad
        
        printf("ret: %d; bad_1 %d; bad %d \n", ret, bad_1, bad);
        if (isBadVersion(ret))
            hight = ret;
        else
            low = ret;

        
        exit = (!((bad_1 == 0) && (bad == 1)));
        printf("hight: %d; low %d; exit %d \n", hight, low, exit);

    }while(!((bad_1 == 0) && (bad == 1)));
        
    return ret;   
}
```

The output is this:

ret: 2; bad_1 0; bad 0
hight: 5; low 2; exit 1

ret: 3; bad_1 0; bad 0
hight: 5; low 3; exit 1

ret: 4; bad_1 0; bad 1
hight: 4; low 3; exit 0

ret: 0; bad_1 0; bad 0
hight: 1; low 0; exit 1

ret: 0; bad_1 0; bad 0
hight: 1; low 0; exit 1

ret: 0; bad_1 0; bad 0
hight: 1; low 0; exit 1

Just few line of output.

At the 3rd iteration exit = 0, so the while condition is false, but seems to continue te loop. I have no debbugger, since I'm using a free version of leetcode.

I cannot understand what is happening, anyone has some idea? Really thanks :)

Comment: How do you know that the entire function isn't called multiple times?

Comment: Because the exercise is just to implement the function

`int firstBadVersion(int n)`

I don't know what happens out of this scope, but I assume that the function is called just once per test.

Comment: @TKingu, it might be worth your while to *test* that assumption.  For instance, by adding another print statement prior to loop entry.

Comment: minor note: according to the problem description, the version numbers start with 1, but you have int low = 0; in your code. I don't know that fixing this will affect your algorithm, but it's worth mention.

Comment: @YakovGalka you were right! I thought that output meant that there was no exit from the loop, but I was very wrong. It was the second test that was causing the problem. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

There is not a bug with the leetcode. The question's constraint is causing this.

```
1 <= bad <= n <= 2^31 - 1
```

The solution that you are trying may not be efficient.

Since you are using "printf" statements at two places, you are getting

```
Output Limit Exceeded
```

Once you remove both the print statements, you will start getting

```
Time Limit Exceeded
```

To solve this you should have O(log n) approach

Also please update the hight and low to following :

```
        if (bad)
            hight = ret-1;
        else
            low = ret+1;
```

And (low +hight) /2 ===>  low+(hight-low)/2 [To avoid overflow]

Comment: They may indeed require a better algorithm, but that doesn't seem to speak to the question of why they observe the output they report.

Comment: I tried running their code and got Output limit exceeded with the given test cases only. I think since it is Output limit exceeded, leetcode is only showing the first few lines, or they might not be copying the output correctly

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)

The problem is a deadlock in a particular condition that I was not able to see! My solution leverages the binary serch idea, but I think that I use it in a wrong manner. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi @TKingu, you solution seem to work if you update to following :  if (bad)
            hight = ret-1;
        else
            low = ret+1;

Comment: Hi @Loki thank you for your reply. :) Yes, thanks. I discovered it just a few minutes ago. I submitted the solution. Thanks all :)